# Writing device tree file for ti sn65dsi86

Tags: kernel, device-tree, drm

I'm new to device trees, but from all the research I can't find a comprehensive tutorial on writing device trees. If concrete I have an ti sn65dsi86 and I want to connect it to an imx8 chip. Linux has already a [driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/gpu/drm/bridge/ti-sn65dsi86.c) for ti chip in kernel source tree under linux/drivers/gpu/drm/bridge/ti-sn65dsi86.c. [This](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/MIPI-DSI-eDP-Bridge-SN65DSI86-Porting-Problem-on-IMX8MM/m-p/1184338) guy has written a device tree for that driver. But where the hell he got all that properties names like **ti,dp-lanes**?? I tried to derive that names from the device driver but no luck. Everything is similar but still different.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally I managed to find proper documents and I share them for those who are in same situation.

First my concrete example. It was as simple as looking into this path inside of the linux kernel source tree:

```
Documentation/devicetree/bindings/display/bridge/ti,sn65dsi86.yaml
```

I could not find all properties listed in the above example from the nxp forum, but at list few mandatory to get ti chip to work (at least in theory, didn't tested yet)

Another story is the device tree official [specification](https://www.devicetree.org/specifications/) and all other dts specific details inside of linux kernel -> [here](https://docs.kernel.org/6.1/devicetree/usage-model.html).

And last, a good introduction to device trees. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6IW7JJQASc), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nz6aBffv-Ek) or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_NyYEBxfn8).